# Configure pytest.ini with absolute paths

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, config, ini

I need to configure `pytest.ini` with some absolute paths, like this

```
# pytest.ini
[pytest]
testpaths =
    C:\S1\Product\Baseline\PYTHON\lab\tests
    C:\S1\Product\Baseline\PYTHON\lab\template
```

However, it seems not to recognize the paths specified. Where am I wrong?

Comment: You have to escape the backslahes (`C:\\S1\\...`) or use forward slashes.

Comment: it haven't solved

Comment: That should work, I tested it - what have you used?